# How to add a linebreak in a textarea that submits on enter keypress?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular7

I'm working on an angular project, and I have a 'textarea' that is submitted on 'enter' keypress.
Now I'm not able to enter a new line in the text area by pressing 'enter' because that event submits the form.
However, Is there any way to add a new line in the textarea on a custom keypress, Like 'ctrl+enter'?

```
<form #noteForm="ngForm" (keyup.enter)="saveNote()">
  <ng-container>
    <textarea></textarea>
    <div class="note-save-btn">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" [title]="appMessages.saveEditableRecord" (click)="saveNote()"><i
          [class]="appIcons.send" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" [title]="appMessages.clear" (click)="resetData()"><i [class]="appIcons.clear"
          aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    </div>
  </ng-container>
</form>
```

Comment: Try shift+enter?

Comment: Yes, try shift+enter, that should work just out of the box. This is for example how facebook works in web, and is a pretty normal standard, I would say in these type of cases.

Answer (score 1):

you can try

(keydown.control.enter)="yourFuction()"

also you can read this article https://alligator.io/angular/binding-keyup-keydown-events/

Answer (score 1):

To present another option, like Atryom mentioned, you can try shift+enter. It works out of the box and I prefer to use this.

Shift+enter is in my opinion a pretty normal standard, for example Facebook web uses the same style, so users would perhaps feel natural to do just that. Also when submitting, I would check that the value is something else than just spaces (if you aren't doing that already). So this is how I would do:

```
<form #noteForm="ngForm" (keyup.enter)="saveNote()">
  <textarea [(ngModel)]="newMessage" name="newMessage"></textarea>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

and TS:

```
saveNote() {
  if (this.newMessage.trim()) {
    console.log('There is a new message!')
  }
}
```

Demo with changing line with shift+enter: **[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jtaj7m)**

Neter's answer is what you want though, if you want to use another key than shift. Of course this solution will work on that solution as well, since it comes out of the box :)